# IIS https certificates

Tags: iis, https, certificate

I’m migrating the c# web applications and data apis I've developed that are hosted on IIS to use http to use SSL / TSL (https).

I have not setup certificates with https before and was wondering if it’s possible to use the same certificate on all apps / data apis on the IIS server or if I need to have 1 certificate per site?

I was hoping I can register a single certificate at the IIS server level and register this on all the child sites…. Or is this magical thinking?

Comment: the phrase you want to research is wildcard SSL certificates - assuming that's appropriate to your needs (i.e. the sites are on the same domain, and you want certificates for subdomains)

Comment: Thanks I'll google that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the same certificate would depend on the name used and the type of usage. If both the same, and the certificate is in the machine personal store and is accessible to IIS, the certificate may be used by multiple sites/services.

As someone else indicated, you may also be able to do this with a wildcard certificate if the domain is the same but the host name is different between services, although the usage would need to be the same (presumably server authentication).

Comment: Thanks.  I'll check this out further along with the wildcard SSL certificates.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a single certificate that is good for multiple sites. I know GoDaddy offers this as a service (for a fee) and it's possible with Certbot and LetsEncrypt certificates. This can occasionally cause issues with Safari - their handling of multiple-domain certificates is slightly broken - but my experience would suggest that it's only a problem if you're doing an immediate redirect from one domain to another, using the same multi-domain certificate for both.

Comment: Ok good to know thanks.